# Ebook (Kindle?) involving a teenager railroaded into becoming a superhero versus aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel, ebooks

I read this as an ebook, probably a Kindle book, in the last five years or so (so read within 2015, although I think the book was older). The protagonist is a teenage male who does something involving saving a girl (I think associated with a prominent politician?) of about the same age in a situation involving alien invaders. He wakes up to find out he's been convicted of a heinous crime with his punishment being put into a suit that gives him powers to fight aliens who are trying to invade Earth. I vaguely remember that the powers are semi-random, but generally involve a combination of increased toughness and the ability to spout various energy beams. I think there is an established hero team who usually takes credit for the victories. The expectation is that most such convicts will die in battle (and many do), but he actually survives, through a combination of luck and exploiting the system. I think the girl he saved becomes aware of him, and starts an effort to bring him back to a normal status.

I remember there were multiple books in the series, and I think I actually bought the second one in the series, although I think I balked at buying later entries, although I don't recall why.

Comment: Is the fact it was an ebook, or even on Kindle, relevant? It was just a “story” or “book”?

Comment: It is relevant in that some ebooks are only available as ebooks, or only on the Kindle site, which can cut down on the search. And it was a novel-length book as I remember it. As noted above, I think there were later books in the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. *[Trainee Superhero](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VHJ9T8C)* by C.H. Aalberry

[image: Front cover of Trainee Superhero]

> **Training to be a superhero is so dangerous that I'm more likely to graduate to a coffin than a cape!**
> But I don't care, because being a superhero is all I've wanted since the day the day alien saucers came out of space and started attacking the Earth. They tore up mountains and cities with ease, killing millions of innocent people. The only thing that stood between Earth and Armageddon was small teams of superheroes who rose up to save the day.
>
> But we are losing the war for Earth, and even the superheroes are dying in their dozens.
>
> **And I might be next.**

The person he saves is a friend of his, who apparently is also the daughter of The General, one of the premier superheroes of the world. Powers come from reverse-engineered alien technology, operate intuitively, and have limited power supplies.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm pretty sure the reason I did not continue buying the books is that they are not full-length books, but rather 70 page pieces.